# Android: grab a piece of an ImageView

Tags: android, image

I have an ImageView from which I want to copy a piece of it in the shape of a circle that I can then re-display to the user at a larger than original size to simulate a zoom effect. Would I use bitmaps for that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.... you can try to get a Bitmap that represents the ImageView you are working with. Before, you have to enable the caching (by invoking the [setDrawingCacheEnabled(true)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setDrawingCacheEnabled%28boolean%29) method). To get the Bitmap representation of the image, you can use the [getDrawingCache()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getDrawingCache%28boolean%29) method.

Once you get that Bitmap, you can resize it or make any other changes you want. Then, you can create a Rect object with the portion of the bitmap you want to draw, then you draw that rect using this method: [drawBitmap(Bitmap, Rect origin, Rect destination, Paint)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.Paint%29).